In Exodus 17:16, why did the LXX render "secret hand" instead of "hand above the throne of Yah"?
The NET translators said,

The line here is very difficult. The Hebrew text has כִּי־יָד עַל־כֵּס
יָהּ (ki yad ʾal kes yah, “for a hand on the throne of Yah”). If the
word is “throne” (and it is not usually spelled like this), then it
would mean Moses’ hand was extended to the throne of God, showing
either intercession or source of power. It could not be turned to mean
that the hand of Yah was taking an oath to destroy the Amalekites. The
LXX took the same letters, but apparently saw the last four (כסיה) as
a verbal form; it reads “with a secret hand.” Most scholars have
simply assumed that the text is wrong, and כֵּס should be emended to
נֵס (nes) to fit the name, for this is the pattern of naming in the OT
with popular etymologies—some motif of the name must be found in the
sentiment. This would then read, “My hand on the banner of Yah.” It
would be an expression signifying that the banner, the staff of God,
should ever be ready at hand when the Israelites fight the Amalekites
again.

Other translators said,

The Greek of Exodus 17:16 provided an opportunity for patristic
theologians to develop an important aspect of their Logos’ doctrine.
The Hebrew text can be translated as following:
‘And he [i.e. Moses] said: “for a hand [is] against the throne of Yah

(kes yah), war for YHWH with Amalek from generation to generation”’.

The Hebrew kes is a hapax and is often said to be identical to kisse’
(throne). But this is far from certain and various emendations have
been suggested. The Septuagint does not have the introductory ‘and he
said’ and reads:

‘For, with a hidden (κρυφαία) hand, the Lord makes war against Amalek
from generation to generation.’

Instead of kisse-yah, the LXX translators read kesuyah, from the root k-s-h, ‘to hide’. The ‘hidden hand’ is specific to the
Septuagint.
Justin Martyr identified it with God’s Son (Dialogue with Trypho 19,
8). For him, the Son is hidden in the Old Testament and the
theological task is one of recovery. For the Fathers, the Son received
various names in the Old Testament, in particular ‘beginning (ἀρχή)’
in Genesis 1:1, ‘Logos’ in Psalms 32:6 (33:6), ‘Wisdom (σοφία)’ in
Proverbs 8:22, all identical to the Logos of John’s Prologue (Origen,
On the First Principles I 2, 1–3 and IV 4, 3). The son is hidden in
the Old Testament, but, thanks to their hermeneutical method,
patristic theologians were able to uncover the passages in which he is
secretly mentioned.
In Exodus 17:16, the four Hebrew letters in question (כִסִּֽתִי) are
also found in Psalm 143:9, albeit in a slightly different
configuration.
There it is rendered as "shelter" or "hidden".

Rescue me from my enemies, O LORD; I run to you to hide me.

Because of this, we can suspect with more certainty that the LXX has
the correct rendering.
From my observation, Exodus 17:16 should be translated this way:

for he said, ""With a hidden hand YHWH wages war against Amalek from generation to generation."


What can we take from all this?

Even Jewish commentators say this is obscure.

@PerryWebb – I am strongly convinced that it says, "For with a hidden hand YHWH wages war against Amalek from generation to generation ." This makes the most sense and flows perfectly with the context.

The Bible is not a document that can be simply edited to "makes sense to me".  The text is what it is.  This is simply one of thousands of places the LXX is quite different from the MT for a variety of reasons that remain inexplicable.

Dottard, isn't "kesuryah" the word for "covered"? Wouldn't this be a secret hand?

What could be called a substantial answer is detailed by the O.P. Does it leave room for any more comment on the LXX saying "secret hand" instead of "hand above the throne of Yah"? There does appear to be some legitimate points of translation that show the LXX could put it that way.
That only leaves the question at the end to answer:  "What can we take from all this?" Very simply, as the O.P. said at the outset, quoting the N.E.T. translators: "The [Hebrew] line here is very difficult to translate."
A problem arises, however, when the O.P. comments go on to bring in matters of different interpretations as to spiritual, or symbolic meanings perhaps being at the back of various translations of the verse in question. Is there any evidence for the LXX translators being influenced by that, instead of by the Hebrew text itself? Exploring hidden spiritual meanings that only become clear when whole tracts of Old and New Testament passages are invoked is not what the Hermeneutics site is for.
While I agree that there is deep, spiritual teaching to be unearthed about Amalek and God's everlasting hostility to Amalek, how can LXX views be shown to be relevant to why they translated Exodus 17:16 the way they did? At a purely translational level, the O.P. put the case at the start, with the first quote. The quotes that followed then deviated into patristic theologians' interpretations of symbolisms. Is the inference that the men who produced the LXX had been influenced by patristic theologians?. "The Logos doctrine" is not involved with the LXX translation of the Hebrew that is rendered in English, "Jehovah-Nissi".
One translation of the verse in question reads:

"And Moses buildeth an altar, and calleth its name Jehovah-Nissi, and
saith, 'Because a hand [is] on the throne of Jah, war [is] to Jehovah
with Amalek from generation - generation." Young's Literal
Translation

An interesting chapter in a book about the various names of God in the Old Testament is headed "Jehovah Nissi 'The Lord Our Banner'" and delves into a summation of the nation of Amalek trying to wipe Israel out, and why God told Israel to destroy that nation. It offers interpretations as to the spiritual significance of all of that, continuing into the New Testament. The author sets out to answer the question,

"What are these lessons we're to learn? What is the Holy Spirit saying to us [Christians] in this battle between Israel and Amalek at
Rephidim?" Hallowed Be Thy Names, David Wilkerson, p51, 2001

Two excellent questions, but not for this Hermeneutics site; I suggest the Christianity site for that. But if someone can unearth more hermeneutic points as to why the LXX men translated the verse in question the way they did, that would be good.

ChristianitySX threw it over to Hermeneutics, so I'd like to keep it here and get a good answer.

@OneGodOneLord  Smiles. Yes. Perhaps, then, two separate questions need to be asked, one for each site, with reference links to each being given?
